# Android creating obfuscated activity library jar

Tags: android, jar, android-activity, obfuscation, android-library

I would like to create a library jar that contains a few in-app billing activities, why i need them in a jar is that my source code will be given to a company but i dun want the company to be able to change or view this part of the application. I have tried to successfully extract a package containing some activities to a jar and import it to a new project. The new project successfully compile and run but the jar cannot be obfuscated to an extent that the activity names and content become de-compilable to human readable code.

Any ideas from you guys? Thanks a lot.